# Ruby on Rails find using OR

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby

Good day! I'm using AngularJS with Ruby on Rails for the backend, and im wondering how can you use find to search for an object array using either of the 2 words.

```js
console.log(_($scope.reasonOfRejection).find({name: {en: 'Black Flagged'}} || {name: {en: 'Black Flag'}}))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the find_by because find is for ids and you do it like:

```
User.find_by(name: ["Black Flagged", "Black Flag"])
```

Edit: Using js array native find method and assuming this is an array `_($scope.reasonOfRejection)` you can do

```
_($scope.reasonOfRejection).find(({ name }) => (
  name.en === "Black Flagged" || name.en === "Black Flag"
))
```

Find will return the first item that matchs with the condition, if you want to return an array of the matching items use filter instead.

```js
const array = [{name: { en: "another item"}}, {name: { en: "item"}}, {name: { en: "Black Flagged"}}]
const match = array.find(({ name }) => (
      name.en === "Black Flagged" || name.en === "Black Flag"
    ))
    
    console.log(match)
```

Comment: angular.js:13920 TypeError: _(...).find_by is not a function 

error like that shows on the frontend

Comment: Oh sorry, this is frontend related, I thought you were trying to query from the rails side, I'm guessing this is an Array.prototype.find native function, I'll update. the answer

Comment: Yup im trying to query the rails from the frontend.

Comment: Thank you! it works now! I've been loosing braincells this morning because of that.

Comment: Awesome,  just keep in mind that the find method that is being used is related to javascript not rails.